# Efficient PHP algorithm to multiply two 3-digit numbers in all configurations

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to get the results of multiplication of all combinations of two 
3-digit numbers.

I realized that each time I execute a script that does a lot fewer operations than the number of operations in above task, the execution time always exceeds 30 second, and the script halts:

```
    $x = 100;
    $y = 100;
    $z = $x * $y;
    while($this->isMagicNumber($z) == false) {
        if ($x + 1 < 1000) {
            $x++;
        } elseif ($x = 999) {
            if($y + 1 < 1000) {
                $y++;
            }
        }
        $z = $x * $y;
    }
```

This algorithm is by no means efficient, and it does not check all multiplication combinations, and it already takes too long to execute.

What would be the way to find the results of all possible multiplications of two 3-digit numbers?

**Edit:**

The `isMagicNumber()` method might, in fact, be the case why the script takes so long to execute, but, on the other hand, it doesn't seem excessively complicated:

```
private function isMagicNumber($number)
{

    if ($number === strrev($number)) {
        echo $number . ' is a Palindrome';
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Edit 2**
Just a reminder:

> Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a
>   substitute for communication and editing.

Comment: I don't get your algorithm, is it complete? And what's this: `if ($x = 999)`?? But since 555 * 666 is the same as 666 * 555 you can start by using half the number of computations.

Comment: @KIKO This algorithm is by no means correct for the test. It just starts multiplication at `$x = 100` and `$y = 100`. Them it increases `$x` by one until `$x = 999` (the highest 3-digit number). From that point on, it starts to increase `$y` by 1 until `$y` is also less than 999. This does not, obviously, checks all combinations, but I like the idea of using half the number of computations.

Comment: I think most servers could easily do 500,000 multiplications in 30 seconds, it's probably your `$this->isMagicNumber($z)`, which has to be executed every time, that takes the longest time. Try to get rid of this method.

Comment: @KIKO, I've added this method to the question. Do you think this is might be the reason for the long execution time?

Comment: Yes, most definately. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this. This avoids multiplying the same two numbers twice as suggested by @KIKO Software:

```
$min = 100;
$max = 999;

for ($x = $min; $x <= $max; $x++) {
   for ($y = $x; $y <= $max; $y++) {
       $p = $x * $y;
       echo "$x * $y = $p", PHP_EOL;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
100 * 100 = 10000
100 * 101 = 10100
100 * 102 = 10200
...
997 * 997 = 994009
997 * 998 = 995006
997 * 999 = 996003
998 * 998 = 996004
998 * 999 = 997002
999 * 999 = 998001
```

*UPDATE -  Looking at your newly posted `isMagicNumber` method*

Your `$number === strrev($number)` expression will actually never return `true`. As [strrev](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) returns a string and `$number` is a number, your [identical](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) comparison will fail. Currently you are experiencing an endless loop, that surely would take more than 30 seconds to complete. Use `==` instead.

Comment: Such an oversight on my part. Thank you indeed for this useful comment and smart code :)

Comment: You're welcome! Kudos to @KIKO Software as well for suggesting to look into the magic number method :)